# $_SESSION php CONTENT NOT FOUND

Tags: php, session-cookies

I work on php with sessions. So I declared a session at the beginning after with the getAccessToken function I retrieved an access token and I put it in a session on the same file I have another function that calls on this session to retrieve the token access but I did not succeed and when I did a var_dump ==> empty array

I have url will redirect to the acessToken function
the 2nd function will retrieve the data with the results found.

```
public function __construct() {
    session_start();
}

 public function getAcess() {
    if (isset($_GET["code"])) $code = ($_GET["code"]);
    //set cookie
    $url = 'url';
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    $fields = array(...)
    $json = http_build_query($fields);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    if ($response === FALSE) {
        die("Curl failed: " . curL_error($curl));
    }
    curl_close($curl);
    $json_response = json_decode($response, true);
    
    $access_token = $json_response['access_token'];
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $access_token; 
    http_response_code( 302 );
    header("Location: " . 'http://localhost:3000/');
    return true;
}

public function dataWeb()
{
    $access_token = null;
    var_dump(  $_SESSION);
    die();
    
    if(isset($_SESSION['access_token'])){
       
        $access_token = $_SESSION["access_token"];
    } else {
        return http_response_code(403);
    }
    
    $url = 'url';
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        `Authorization: Bearer $access_token`
    ));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    if ($response === FALSE) {
        die("Curl failed: " . curL_error($curl));
    }
    curl_close($curl);
    
    $response =json_decode($response, true);
    
  );
}
```

thanks!

Comment: `$_SESSION['access_token'] = $access_token;` Where was defined `$access_token` ?

Comment: $access_token = $json_response['access_token']; here

Comment: I get the session in wamp/tmp

Comment: Since you've edited your question, same question applies : `$access_token = $json_response['access_token'];` where was defined `$json_response['access_token'];` ?